Can the footer or URL in the footer be removed from a Firebase-generated PDF?
This is my first post, so hopefully I did it right. I will start by saying I know almost nothing about Firebase, so this is probably a long shot, but we are trying to solve an issue with an app built in Firebase by a long-gone developer. The original issue is related to email deliverability of PDFs generated in Firebase. We believe the error to be due to a URL contained in the footer of the PDF. Full disclosure I am an MSP trying to help a customer with this request.
Some months after the dev left, Firebase "suddenly" started putting an entire blank page at the beginning of the PDF and now includes a URL pointing to the web login page of the app the PDF is generated in. The last published version of the app was a few months prior to when the email issue started occurring, so it doesn't appear to be related to anything they have changed internally.
My question is basically: Can we remove the URL and/or footer from the PDF?
We think the URL may be causing the attachment/email to get flagged as malware. VirusTotal.com does not report an issue with the attachment file, and only emails with the Firebase-generated PDFs are getting flagged as malware. All non-attachment emails as well as emails with non-Firebase-generated PDFs are delivered fine.
Thanks for any advice you can provide.
